# What's the replacement for fuslogvw in .net core 2?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

When encountering problems with resolving DLLs and assemblies in general with .Net [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) gave you the ability to log the binding attempts so you could see exactly where it was looking and what was going on.

There is a github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10379) discussing this, but it's not exactly got very much detail on what `COREHOST_TRACE` actually provides, nor the best way to get the output, nor how to interpret the output.

So, is `COREHOST_TRACE` the best option?

If so how is it used?

If not, what's the better option?

I'd like to know the answer to this general question, because it's a useful tool to have and so has uses well beyond my current problem. However I am also trying to fix a specific problem, so I've included details of that below.

I'm using...

- VS 15.7.2
- asp.net core 2.0
- The DLL in question is native, and is [being accessed via `DllImport`](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/blob/master/src/DinkToPdf/WkHtmlToXBindings.cs).

Interestingly the DLL is resolved when I publish a release build, but fails running locally for development builds.

Exception: `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

The DLL in question is beinging copied to the root of the output directory:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Dependencies\wkhtmltox\v0.12.4\32 bit\libwkhtmltox.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <TargetPath>libwkhtmltox.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Are you running the app in 32bit when trying to load the 32bit native dll?

Comment: I have same issue and can not find anything useful in COREHOST_TRACE log. However i found some old discussions on github where people used it and had things like `Property NATIVE_DLL_SEARCH_DIRECTORIES`..

Answer (score 11):

It's a long time since the original question, but as of .NET 5, there is `dotnet trace`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/collect-details.

(I found this via https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12506#issuecomment-895192112.)