# How can I trace failed assembly binding in a dotnet core web project (running in IIS Express)

Tags: .net-core, .net-assembly, iis-express

I'm struggling to find why a certain assembly is not loaded in a dotnetcore 3.1 webproject

(I'm getting `Could not load file or assembly 'MyCool.Services.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`)

If this was a netFw project I would simply fire up [Fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) and find a lot of information about why the assembly binding fails.

Maybe I've overlooked, but I haven't found an alternative way to find this kind of information for a dotnet core project.

A previous post asked it here but doesn't have an answer :
[What's the replacement for fuslogvw in .net core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493071/whats-the-replacement-for-fuslogvw-in-net-core-2)

I also already followed the advice of this SO post : [Inspect dependencies for dynamically loaded library in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792974/inspect-dependencies-for-dynamically-loaded-library-in-net-core) and set ***COREHOST_TRACE=1*** in the package manager console.

[image]

But it seems it's not useful for web projects running is IIS express.. (the log states *dotnet : Couldn't find a project to run.* while I have my project started)

Any advice on ***how the trace my failed assembly binding*** would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 9):

Ok, a bit more perseverance in Googling helped me out....

It turns out that Microsoft has already given us a new "[dotnet-trace analysis utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace)" and  a ton of documentation on [how to trace assembly loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/collect-details).

Steps to use this are :

1. Install the dotnet-trace utility using dotnet tool

> PM> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace

2. Identify the pid of your running application in iis express

> PM> dotnet-trace ps

3. Start tracing :)

> PM> dotnet-trace collect --providers Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime:4
> --process-id <pid>

4. Finally open the trace.nettrace file with the perfview tool from [Github/microsoft/perfview](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview)

I hope this info helps others in not loosing too much time googling around for "how to fuslogvw in dotnetcore" :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me many hours of pain hunting around. It took a bit of learning curve on PerfView but finally sorted it out and was able to get it going. One issue I had was finding where the tracefile was saved. I ended up saving it myself with --output parameter BUT it must have .nettrace extension to work in PerfView

Comment: Could not get the PerfView tool to open the file, however, found out that you can open in Visual Studio, no problems.